# PHP putenv() not updating

Tags: php, apache

On my apache instance it is setting an env variable `APP_ENV=development`. I am trying to change this dynamically on my PHP side (in the instance of firing up test suite) like so:

```
putenv('APP_ENV=testing')
var_dump(getenv('APP_ENV')); // still returns development
```

I have tried:

- Starting php in safe mode in php.ini
- Setting `safe_mode_allowed_env_vars = PHP_ APP_` in php.ini

---

**Update:**

I am using PHP version 5.4.16 and notice that safe mode has been deprecated. I'm not sure if this means putenv will even work for overwriting or even unsetting existing envs?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using an Apache variable, so, you should use `apache_setenv()` and `apache_getenv()`

```
apache_setenv('APP_ENV', 'testing');
```

To recover it use:

```
apache_getenv('APP_ENV');
```

Comment: Wow that seems to work. Why on earth would php have two different ways of setting envs? It seems now you need to detect what server type is running to properly set an env?!

Answer (score 0):

The docs say the list needs to be comma delimited.

try PHP_,APP_

Comment: Sorry guys, I wrote the question wrong but I am setting it like `APP_ENV=testing`

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me:

```
Env::getRepository()->set('VARIABLE_NAME', 'VALUE');
```